# Google login option isn't working on iOS Safari 12.5

Tags: support, login, google, ios

I'm trying to login with Safari on Stack Overflow from my old iPhone 6 with iOS 12.5.5.

But when I tap on "Login with Google" nothing is happening and the login does not work.

Why?

Comment: You aren't using a [supported](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) version of Safari of iOS, so this is not surprising.

Comment: Right, thank you :(
There isn't any way to login from my phone?

Comment: Updating it would be the obvious choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't new updates. iPhone 6 and its apps are no longer updated.

Comment: Time for a new phone then. If you're using unsupported hardware, you can't expect websites to ensure that their site works on it.

Comment: Are you able to install a different browser on it?

Comment: I'm able to install only Opera, because other browsers are not compatible with my iOS version. But not even in Opera the login work.

Comment: I noticed this too. I'm also using the same phone and the same OS version. It is not just the login option, major functionality is no longer supported. I can no longer answer, comment or vote. I  can't even see full comments. I noticed this about 2 months ago, I supposed that's around when they dropped support for old mobile devices.